# Redirect from different port to subdomain - htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I created a Digital Ocean instance to install wordpress website 5 days ago. I already have my own domain, and created DNS Subdomain blog.mydomain.com.
the server runs both nginx and apache so my apache port is 8082.
Below is my actual wordpress URL looks like.

`www.example.com:8082/wordpress/`

Something which i have tried is below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com:8082/wordpress\
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9-]+)/? http://$1.example.com [R=301,NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Now my expected result is from

`www.example.com:8082/wordpress\`
to

```
blog.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this by configuring Nginx to proxy the requests to Apache, by modifying the Nginx server block of your subdomain.

```
server {
    server_name blog.mydomain.com;
    ...
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://www.example.com:8082/wordpress/;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: The above is actually putting the page to redirection.
i want the url to be like  ```blog.expostall.com``` and ```blog.expostall.com/post1``` instead of ```www.example.com:8082/wordpress``` or ```www.example.com:8082/wordpress/post1```